# Aligning object to face normal with local rotation MaxScript

Tags: 3d, alignment, maxscript

My script aligns object to face like this: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdkP9.png]

But i need to get this: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNWeT.png]

there is a code i used:

```
faces = (polyOp.getFaceSelection $Box001) as array
face = faces[1]
theMatrix = matrixFromNormal(polyOp.getFaceNormal $Box001 face)
theMatrix.row4 = polyOp.getFaceCenter $Box001 face
$object.transform = theMatrix
```

Help me, friends :)

Comment: When you compute a rotation from a single vector, the rotation around that vector is unconstrained, which is exactly the situation here.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Is there some way to get rotation around this vector? 3dmax can get it when you just select face [link](https://i.imgur.com/SY0IjJT.png) but i dont know how to use it with maxscript

Comment: Use the transformation matrix of `$Box001` itself, and set `.row4` to the same.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog could you please show example in code how to achieve this?

Comment: https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2018/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_3B001F21_8FE9_4663_A972_E648682A0ACD_htm